# XCode Syntax highlighting issue

Tags: xcode

I have a weird thing happening in Xcode.  (BTW I'm a bit new to Xcode.)

I have a simple ViewController class with no custom code in the header.  e.g.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FooViewController : UIViewController
{

}

@end
```

But the syntax highlighting does not seem to be working.  For instance  the "UIViewController" text is black, but in my other classes its purple.  I also noticed in the Symbol Navigator this class was not shown, but the others were, it's as if Xcode knows nothing about this class??  Something is wrong here.  Can anyone allude to what it might be?

Comment: Have you set the project to be Mac OSX or iOS - UIKit is only in iOS

Comment: I think so - when I debug it all works and the iPhone simulator pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reloaded the project and this funny bug seemed to go away. Hmmm strange one.